# Arxiv and BibTex and Bibliography style for .bbl

Tags: bibliographies, arxiv

I am trying to submit an article to arxiv, but it doesn't seem to like Bibtex (ie. running .bib files because it takes too much database).

So I went back to .bbl files (i.e. \input{references.bbl}). However, I would like to have the style of alpha (eg. [Ka90]) instead of the default style, which is numbering (eg. [3]). The alpha style gives a shortened version of name and the date.

Any ideas on how to do that? (Adding \bibliographystyle{\alpha} doesn't do anything because I think it refers to bibtex).

Thank you

Comment: Running on your machine an example with  `\bibliographystyle{\alpha}` will generate a bbl file that is read by LaTeX. Give that file a unique name, delete the bibtex relatex stuff and input the bbl in your document where the bibliography is supposed to be.